# Webscraping - get coordinates from google maps network

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am a bit of a novice webscraper-hobbyist and I'm trying to figure out how I can extract the coordinates from a google maps element on a [webpage](https://www.hemnet.se/salda/villa-5rum-bunkeflostrand-malmo-kommun-stenoregatan-72-1967930410921603954).

There is not trace of the coordinates in the elements tab in the developer tools. However when searching for the relevant coordinates in the network tab there is a XHR-entry "SingleImageSearch" that has a payload with the coordinates of interest:

[image]

My question is about how I can extract this information (coordinates) using python.

I am currently making a request for this link (as shown below) to fetch other information from the website that can be found in the elements tab, but I have never tried to fetch any network traffic before and I am at a complete loss.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = HTMLSession()
res = session.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
```

Any help on this would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can get lat/lon coordinates from this page:

```py
import requests

# url = "https://www.hemnet.se/salda/villa-5rum-bunkeflostrand-malmo-kommun-stenoregatan-72-1967930410921603954"

api_url = "https://www.hemnet.se/graphql"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0"
}

payload = {
    "operationName": "saleMap",
    "query": "query saleMap($id: ID!) {\n  sales(ids: [$id]) {\n    id\n    coordinates {\n      lat\n      long\n      __typename\n    }\n    housingForm {\n      name\n      symbol\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n",
    "variables": {"id": "1967930410921603954"}, # <-- ID from URL
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers).json()
# print(data)

lat, lon = (
    data["data"]["sales"][0]["coordinates"]["lat"],
    data["data"]["sales"][0]["coordinates"]["long"],
)

print(f"{lat=} {lon=}")
```

Prints:

```
lat=55.56008618734383 lon=12.911069674273191
```

Comment: This worked very well, thank you!
Is there any good resource if I want to learn more about these network requests and how to "intercept" them?